# nth term of a sequence

Tags: math, binary-search

I have two sequence:

**1.**

```
8 27 64 125 ...
```

**2.**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ....
```

Now take one element from **1** and another from **2** and mutiply them. Repeat this. Arrange the numbers obtained in increasing order.

```
8 16 24 27 32 40 48 54 56 64 64 ...
```

How can we efficiently find the `n`-th number of this new sequence?

Comment: Please be more specific how the result is defined; it is not clear to me from the example.

Comment: can you give a sample example of finding nth element?

Comment: @Codor: It seems to be a cartesian product of the two sequences.

Comment: first take cartesian product of two sequence and then arrange them in increasing order

Comment: This is likely to be a more mathematical than programming problem. Without knowing anything about how the sequences are generated I'm not sure you can do anything more than a brute force approach of finding the nth number. If you do know how the sequences are generated (and in this case it seems to be `(n+1)^3` and `n`) then it is much more about looking at the mathematical properties of the terms involved...

Comment: 8*1 8*2 8*3 27*1 8*4 8*5 8*6 27*2 ...... so on.

Comment: Why do you need to do this out of interest? I'm wondering if there might be a better way of doing this or is it just an academic exercise?

Comment: I am solving programming problem. I have reduced the problem to this.

Comment: Read about generating Hamming numbers and use similar approach  (Dijkstra one or lazy evaluation one)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicate elements in the result then I would use modified **Sieves of Eratosthenes** to mark all the final series numbers and then create table of the series itself. Here small **C++** example:

```cpp
// globals
const int N0=4;
const int N1=6;
const int N2=N0*N1;
const int M=(N0+2)*(N0+2)*(N0+2)*N1;
int f0(int x) { x+=2; return x*x*x; }   // x = <0,N0)
int f1(int x) { x+=1; return x; }       // x = <0,N1)
int f2[N2],n;                           // x = <0,n )

// locals
int x,y;
BYTE soe[M+1];
AnsiString txt="";

// debug print series
for (txt+="f0(x) = ",x=0;x<N0;x++) { txt+=f0(x); txt+=" "; } txt+="\r\n";
for (txt+="f1(x) = ",x=0;x<N1;x++) { txt+=f1(x); txt+=" "; } txt+="\r\n";

tbeg();
// compute sieve
for (x=0;x<=M;x++) soe[x]=0;
for (x=0;x<N0;x++)
 for (y=0;y<N1;y++)
  soe[f0(x)*f1(y)]=1;
// reorder it to table
for (x=0,n=0;x<=M;x++)
 if (soe[x]) { f2[n]=x; n++; }
tend(); txt+="computed in "+tstr(1)+"\r\n";

// debug print ordered series as function of x ... counting from 0
for (txt+="f2(x) = ",x=0;x<n;x++) { txt+=f2[x]; txt+=" "; } txt+="\r\n";

Form1->mm_log->Lines->Add(txt);
```

result:

```
f0(x) = 8 27 64 125 
f1(x) = 1 2 3 4 5 6 
computed in [   0.003 ms]
f2(x) = 8 16 24 27 32 40 48 54 64 81 108 125 128 135 162 192 250 256 320 375 384 500 625 750
```

Just ignore `tbeg(),tend(),tstr()` and string `Form1->mm_log,txt` stuff or rewrite to your platform/**IDE**. This is not optimized yet and can be improved a lot ... for example you can use single bit per sieve element instead `BYTE` or even avoid of using the whole sieve table in memory (by clever ordering/partitioning the subresults).

In case duplicates are present in output then you need use sieve as counter of element not just boolean and reconstruct it accordingly.